# How do you install DoReMi?

Tags: install, require, load, cycling, iteration

I found that [DoReMi](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DoReMi) is a better way of resizing windows in emacs, but DoReMi is not in the Melpa package repository. I looked at the Emacs Wiki and [`doremi.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/doremi.el) was there but I'm not too sure how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

You install it the same way you install any code from any random .el file: copy it into your `load-path`, and then call `require`.

`require` takes one argument, which is the name of the feature to load. Add `(require 'doremi)` to your init file, and Emacs will go looking for `doremi.el` (and `doremi.elc`, in case it’s been byte–compiled) in every directory mentioned in `load-path`. Once found, Emacs will `load` it. Done.